# Why Karma unit tests with jasmine for a Node typescript project shows coverage including a dependency?

Tags: typescript, karma-jasmine, istanbul, karma-coverage

As the subject says, the code coverage of our project includes a node dependency. However note that the source code of this npm dependency is part of the project as well, as we develop and publish it.
Here is the structure of the project:

- root

  - main_project

    - karma.conf.ts
    - src and other files to be tested and for which the coverage is to be generated
    - test
  - side_project which is packaged and published to npm and used across multiple projects including this one

    - src etc.

So, even though my karma config is within the main_project(src and src/* in image) folder here, which I want to test and generate coverage for, karma includes the side_project(petreol-api-wrapper in the image) as well in the coverage, like this:
[image: screenshot of karma coverage]

Here is my relevant karma config:

```
const testRecursivePath = "test/*Test.ts";
const srcOriginalRecursivePath = "src/**/*.ts";
frameworks: ["jasmine"],
reporters: [
    "progress",
    "junit",
    "coverage-istanbul"
],
files: [
    testRecursivePath,
    {
        pattern: srcOriginalRecursivePath,
        included: false,
        served: true
    }
],
preprocessors: {
    [testRecursivePath]: ["webpack", "coverage"]
},
```

Could someone please help me with this?

Answer (score 0):

There is an option to exclude files in `karma.conf`, For example, below config will exclude all `ts` files inside `node_modules` folder. You may need to work on relative path which I have provided in below example. You can ignore all using `**.*`

```
exclude: [
        "node_modules/**/*.ts"
]
```

to be used as

```
const testRecursivePath = "test/*Test.ts";
const srcOriginalRecursivePath = "src/**/*.ts";
frameworks: ["jasmine"],
reporters: [
    "progress",
    "junit",
    "coverage-istanbul"
],
files: [
    testRecursivePath,
    {
        pattern: srcOriginalRecursivePath,
        included: false,
        served: true
    }
],
exclude: [
        "node_modules/**/*.ts"
]
preprocessors: {
    [testRecursivePath]: ["webpack", "coverage"]
},
```

Comment: Thanks for the suggestion. However, it didn't help, and the other project is still shown in the coverage.