# How to produce test coverage report for tests written with Karma Jasmine for Typescript website project

Tags: angular, typescript, unit-testing, karma-jasmine

Context

This is typescript website, that is built by Bazel, it has a few unit tests

[image]

I've trying to understand and use different approaches on how to product that test coverage report:

1. https://www.npmjs.com/package/karma-typescript
2. [Why Karma unit tests with jasmine for a Node typescript project shows coverage including a dependency?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/62475381/why-karma-unit-tests-with-jasmine-for-a-node-typescript-project-shows-coverage-i)
3. https://typescript.tv/testing/typescript-code-coverage-with-karma/#Update-export-1

The 1. has a super minimal example of how to configure, and then also a cookbook for different type of project - https://github.com/monounity/karma-typescript/tree/master/examples/angular2 note that my website is not run with `ng s` is run by Bazel and it uses Scala Play framework

The 2. is a SO question but without any useful or accepted answer

The 3. one is quite detailed and have been trying to follow it without success

Some configuration ask me to change a tsconfig.json which I don't even have, not sure how to use include/exclude options in the Karma.conf.js. - https://www.typescriptlang.org/docs/handbook/tsconfig-json.html

**I know that this seems to be asking a lot of questions but I need to know what is the way to configure Karma/Jasmine to produce a test coverage report**

The *.ts files are under /app/**/*.ts including the unit tests itself

Here is my progress so far using karma-typescript:

Karma.conf.js

```json
module.exports = function(config) {
    config.set({
        frameworks: ["jasmine", "karma-typescript"],
        files: [
            "app/**/*.ts" // *.tsx for React Jsx
        ],
        preprocessors: {
            "**/*.ts": "karma-typescript" // *.tsx for React Jsx
        },
        reporters: ["progress", "karma-typescript"],
        browsers: ["Chrome"],
        karmaTypescriptConfig: {
            bundlerOptions: {
                entrypoints: /\.spec\.ts$/
            }
        }
    });

};
```

The package.json did not even have a "test" action (npm test)

```json
"scripts": {
    "postinstall": "./postinstall.sh",
    "test": "karma start"
},
"dependencies": {
    .....
    "eslint-plugin": "^1.0.1",
    "google-closure-deps": "^20220502.0.0",
    "karma-typescript": "^5.5.3",
    .....
}
```

And then since I did not know how to continue I tried to follow the detailed steps for option 3 (I'm aware is not for karma-typescript) but now I'm so lost

The only progress I have made is that now when I run "npm test" "karma  start" is executed and it produces a bunch of errors on console.

> [91m11 07 2022 18:29:24.928:ERROR [compiler.karma-typescript]:
> [39mapp/LTools/misc-node-scripts/bundle.ts(154,30): error TS2569:
> Type 'IterableIterator' is not an array type or a string type.
> Use compiler option '--downlevelIteration' to allow iterating of
> iterators.
>
> [91m11 07 2022 18:29:24.928:ERROR [compiler.karma-typescript]:
> [39mapp/LTools/misc-node-scripts/bundle.ts(154,64): error TS2569:
> Type 'Set' is not an array type or a string type. Use compiler
> option '--downlevelIteration' to allow iterating of iterators.
>
> [91m11 07 2022 18:29:24.928:ERROR [compiler.karma-typescript]:
> [39mapp/LTools/module-checker/module-checker.ts(19,6): error TS2551:
> Property 'option' does not exist on type 'typeof
> import("/home/c-mgracia/press/main/cake/node_modules/commander/typings/index")'.
> Did you mean 'Option'?
>
> [91m11 07 2022 18:29:24.928:ERROR [compiler.karma-typescript]:
> [39mapp/LTools/performance/snowrunner/src/snowflakesession.ts(4,25):
> error TS2307: Cannot find module 'snowflake-promise'.
>
> [91m11 07 2022 18:29:24.928:ERROR [compiler.karma-typescript]:
> [39mapp/LTools/performance/snowrunner/src/snowflakesession.ts(5,33):
> error TS2307: Cannot find module
> '../node_modules/snowflake-promise/prod/types/ConnectionOptions'.
>
> [91m11 07 2022 18:29:24.928:ERROR [compiler.karma-typescript]:
> [39mapp/LTools/performance/snowrunner/src/snowrunner.ts(2,25): error
> TS2307: Cannot find module 'figlet'.
>
> [91m11 07 2022 18:29:24.928:ERROR [compiler.karma-typescript]:
> [39mapp/LTools/performance/snowrunner/src/snowrunner.ts(3,33): error
> TS2307: Cannot find module 'gradient-string'.
>
> [91m11 07 2022 18:29:24.928:ERROR [compiler.karma-typescript]:
> [39mapp/LTools/performance/snowrunner/src/snowrunner.ts(4,24): error
> TS2307: Cannot find module 'yargs'.

Comment: This question does have a clear focus : "what is the way to configure Karma/Jasmine to produce a test coverage report" is even in the title, everying else is the "what have you tried/struggled part

Comment: For the persons that are asking for "more focus" could you provide an example related to the problem that I'm explaining ? there is only one task at hand "produce a test coverage report" tool sets and languages are explained, dont just ask to close, provide me more details please